# swift use button to let collectionView be hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, hidden

Thank you for reading my question,
like the title says, how can I use a button to control the `collectionView` show/hide like `hidden = false`.

> I want the `collectionView` to hide it in `viewDidload(ViewController)` method and show when I press the button.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath 
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
    {
        collectionView.hidden = true
    }
```

I just can call `collectionView` in func , How can I do this?

Comment: where do you wanna add the button to?

Comment: I forget to var collectionView ...  so my `self ` has't member collectionView.The problem has been resolved.Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewDidLoad, `self.collectionView.hidden = true`. Then you can toggle the hide/show using the following method:

```
@IBAction func toggleCollectionViewHideShow(sender: UIButton) {
   self.collectionView.hidden = !self.collectionView.hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with any object of your ViewController. You need a UIButton action.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton){
   self.collectionView.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
@IBAction func toggleCollectionViewHideShow(sender: UIButton) 
{
 self.collectionViewCn.isHidden = !self.collectionViewCn.isHidden
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please describe the code in order to make it understandable to all users. Thanks